# How to update records on production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Ruby on Rails
We recently added a field to a table and that field is populated when a record is created. However, we have older records in the table. Meaning the newly added fields are not populated in those records. Now I need to update them.
So,.what is the best way to update the older records? The value to populate needs some computation before storing.
The server is hosted on AWS.
I know rake task is one option. But are there any other efficient ways?

Comment: If this is a "one-shot deal", meant to run only once, I usually go with a Rails migration to "fix" the data to be compliant with the new configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative you could consider is writing a script that connects directly to your postgres DB, does the computation and updates your old records through a sql query.

Comment: I ended up using script idea. I created an script with ActiveRecord support that connects to the remote DB and does the required update. It was fairly simple. Better than using rake task which requires me to push the codes to server, ssh into the server and run rake task. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'll put these updates in your migrations file. Not helpful for migrations you've already done, but for any database modification which will affect older records, always put the required changes in the migration file.